# PagedList.MVC Refresh Partial View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am calling a partial view with render action

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetEmployerJobs", "Job"); }
```

my GetEmployerJobs controller action looks like this

```
public ActionResult GetEmployerJobs(int? p, string id)
{
    var jobs = repository.GetEmployerJobs(id);

    int pageSize = 1;
    int pageNumber = (p ?? 1);

    return PartialView("~/Views/Dashboard/Employer/_GetEmployerJobPartial.cshtml", jobs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

And my partial view contains the pager

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, p => Url.Action("GetEmployerJobs", "Job", new { p }))
```

The call to GetEmployerJobs is a child action so it is not working, if i remove child action attribute, only the partial view is rendered upon pager click.

How do i refresh this partial view after pager click, I looked around for options such as using AJAX but couldn't figure out how to implement it using PagedList.MVC

Answer (score 0):

You Can use ajax to refresh the partial view without refreshing the entire page

First install package jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive using command

**Install-Package jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive**

and make sure **jQuery-xxxx.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js** are included before the pager

Add the code line `@{ Html.RenderAction("GetEmployerJobs", "Job"); }`  between `<div id='ajaxpanel'>` tag with id ajaxpanel

then add this  java script code after the pager in the partial view

```js
 <script> 
    $(".pagination > li > a").attr('data-ajax-update', '#ajaxpanel');
    $(".pagination > li > a").attr('data-ajax-mode', 'replace');
    $(".pagination > li > a").attr('data-ajax', 'true');
 </script>
```